# RxJS pipe method ignores objectMode for streams

Tags: node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

There is a method called [pipe](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/pipe.html). Consider code bellow:

```
class S extends stream.Transform {
    constructor () {
      super({objectMode: true})
    }
    _transform (data, enc, cb) {
      console.log('vm', data, enc)
      this.push(null, data)
      cb()
    }
 }
var s = new S()
factors // just a stream of some objects
  .do((x) => console.log(x)) // I see an object here
  .pipe(s) // but here the object casts to string
```

How can I force Rx to not ignore `objectMode`?

Comment: I don't know anything about node streams, but looking at the source for [pipe](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/pipe.js), it seems it explicitely onNext all events as strings using `String(event)` - so to answer your question... you probably can't with the current implementation.

Comment: @Nupf Hey, Thanks! I created  a ticket in their repo